# What is the difference between A => 1 and 'A' => 1?

Tags: raku

Using the Perl 6 REPL:

```
> Map.new: 'A' => 1, 'B' => 2;
Map.new((:A(1),:B(2)))
> Map.new: A => 1, B =>2;
Map.new(())
```

I previously thought that `A => 1` and `'A' => 1` would be identical because `=>` is supposed to autoquote the word to its left, but in the second example the pairs seem to disappear.

---

Disclaimer: This tripped me up earlier today, so I'm posting it as Q&A in case it is helpful to someone else too. Also feel free to add your own answers.

Answer (score 4):

In general, `A => 1` and `'A' => 1` create equivalent Pair objects. But inside a subroutine or method call, the first syntax is parsed as named arguments instead of as a Pair. And ***in methods, unused named arguments are ignored***, which explains the empty `Map` created in your second statement. So, you have to take a little extra care that the parser does not interpret your pairs as named arguments. The following are all distinguishable from named arguments:

```
Map.new: (A=>1, B=>2);    # extra set of parentheses 
Map.new: 'A'=>1, 'B'=>2;  # quote the keys
Map.new: 'A', 1, 'B', 2;  # Don't use fat commas `=>`
```

By the way, this also demonstrates another reason to use the colon `:` instead of `()` for method calls. Using parentheses may not be as clean:

```
Map.new( A=>1, B=>2);  # oops, named arguments
Map.new((A=>1, B=>2)); # extra set of parentheses solves the issue
```

Comment: Part of this problem is that every signature has an implicit `*%_` for these named parameters. I've started adding an `*%_ ()` to every signature to prevent this. I think this stealth behavior is bad for users.

Comment: @briandfoy agreed

Comment: @briandfoy The reason for `*%` on methods is because of the Liskov substitution principle. If it didn't, and a subtype redefined a method, it wouldn't get called if a user gave it a named argument that it didn't explicitly accept. If the superclass did accept that named argument, it would call the wrong method silently. Many people who work on the core had at one point the same perception as you, they don't anymore.

Comment: I know what they did. I still think people are going to hate it and this is going to be a common problem for the casual user.

Comment: @BradGilbert So, if I'm understanding correctly, we would have other confusing silent failures if objects didn't pass their unused arguments on unencumbered to their subtypes. Thanks for the explanation. It's good to know that it was actually a well-thought out decision.

Answer (score 1):

In `'A' => 1`, the `'A'` is a string, in `A => 1` the `A` is an identifier.

---

To demonstrate related concepts, here is an imaginary discussion, including some questions and answers ...

If the key is a syntactic identifier, and it's directly in an argument list, then it will be taken as a named argument. Otherwise it will be a Pair

`"foo" => "bar"` isn't a syntactic identifier, `(foo => "bar")` isn't directly in the argument list, nor is `(:foo<bar>)`.

`foo => "bar"` and `:foo("bar")` are equivalent and, both have a key that is a syntactic identifier

Question: Does `:ident<foo>` promote to `"ident"=>"foo"` outside of an argument list?

That's the wrong way round. They're always a Pair; however, they get promoted to named arguments when at the top level of an argument list

Question: Does `:2<>` and `:2nd` not turn into pairs just for the convenience?

`:2<>` is a syntax error.

`:2nd` is just `:nd(2)`

Q: why not "2nd" => "True"? because not identifier?

Also because it'd not be very useful
Imagine trying to implement s:2nd/foo/bar/
Would have to take a slurpy hash and try to parse the number out of it

Q: if the thing after the : can only be an identifier in the basic case, then it's all well and good to do things with the non-identifiers..

Yeah, anything non-identifier after it is a special form